# Unable to view the health check result of AWS ECS Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a some task in AWS ECS service, the health check of the task fails, however there is no logs for the result of health check in the control panel. but when I check the container in my local, It works well and is healthy. how can I see the error logs of the health check?

Comment: If you are talking about the load balancer health check, there isn't much of a log anywhere for that. You need to look at the health check settings in the target group and double-check they are correct. Also check that the ECS task's security group allows traffic from the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I see the error logs of the health check?

Health checks just expose a [health status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) of `HEALTHY`, `UNHEALTHY` or `UNKNOWN`.

There are no logs for a health check specifically.

I would recommend reading this [official Knowledge Center article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-task-container-health-check-failures) on how to troubleshoot container health check failures for Amazon ECS tasks.